# Silence Javascript stack traces in htmlunit

Tags: android-studio, stack-trace, htmlunit

I have configured my program to continue past JavaScript exceptions:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_ESR);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);      // #1
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
```

The result is that the program continues to run, even if it encounters JavaScript errors, as expected based on the setting #1 above.

The problem is that errors are still getting logged.  For example:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "jQuery" is not defined.
```

which is then followed by over **one hundred lines of stack trace** that I don't care about.

I thought maybe there might be a `public void setPrintContentOnScriptError(Boolean enabled)` method in `WebClientOptions`, but I did not find that.

How can I prevent JavaScript stack traces from cluttering the output when running htmlunit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize the log configuration.
Please have a look at https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/logging.html.